# Rectangle Arranged Data Parsing as Squares into Two Dimensionl Array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I've been tackling this one problem and currently having a lack of ideas of how to parse a numerical data divided into small snippets of data squares into two dimensional array. Data is arranged in rectangle like form (Supposedly similar as it would be in a file/text file). Data would look like like in the picture provided below, numerical values can be completely random so they do not matter. I would need to parse all possible squares *(red, blue and green highlighted ones are an example*) that can be found within that rectangle into an array of square objects .

**The problem I am facing is figuring out the way to read all possible square combinations within this rectangle and properly writing them to the console. (I am sure if I could read and print them properly to the console I won't be having too much trouble storing that data either.)**. I've been thinking of how to do it in several ways, but unfortunately all those attempts and ponderings didn't click in my mind properly. I am not sure if my thoughts would be of any help to you, but here is a snippet of my miserable attempt at figuring this parsing problem. I am trying to print to the console at least 3x3 squares that could be found within the rectangle (matrix/2D array - you name it). It'd be great if anyone could help me figure out how to read and print all possible squares that can be found within that rectangle.

EDIT: Since I can't post images due to website restrictions, I am leaving the link:

[Data Image](http://puu.sh/cY5er/d7182188a1.png)

EDIT2: I also noticed that square highlighted in green colour is incorrect due to not being actually a square, please ignore that and excuse me for inconvenience and possible confusion.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] rectangle = {
            {4, 9, 6, 2, 6},
            {3, 5, 1, 6, 4},
            {8, 1, 5, 6, 2},
            {1, 1, 6, 2, 2}
            }; 
    int m = 5; // row length
    int n = 4; // column length
    int min = 3; // minimum square row/column length for iteration
    int start = 0;
    int step =  0;
    for (int x = 0; x < n-1; x++){
        for(int y = start;  y < m-1; y++){
            if (y < min){ // no idea how to make this part work
                System.out.print(rectangle[x][y] + " ");
                step++;
            }
            if(Math.pow(min, 2) == step && x != n - 1){
                // once here save the square, initialize new one;
                System.out.println("");
                step = 0;
                start++;
                y = start;
                x++;
            }
            // all squares have been read in x-th column, moving more to the right
            if( x == n - 1 && y == min - 1 && x != y){
                y = start + 1;
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you just want any possible square in a grid or do the squares have some other property, which identifies it as a valid square?

Comment: I need to fetch any possible square in the grid, there are no other property for differentiating them.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm works as follows:

- determine all points that can be the upper-left-hand-corners of a square in a given rectengle
- for each of these determine all possible sizes, so that the complete square is in the rectange
- do thins with the new-found squares (in this case print two oppisite corners)

  ```
  int[][] rectangle = {
          {4, 9, 6, 2, 6},
          {3, 5, 1, 6, 4},
          {8, 1, 5, 6, 2},
          {1, 1, 6, 2, 2}
          }; 
  int m = 5; // row length
  int n = 4; // column length
  int min = 3; // minimum square row/column length for iteration

  //Take all possible upper-left-hand-corners
  for(int row = 0; row <= n - min; row++){
      for(int column = 0; column <= m - min; column++){
          //Determine all possible square sizes from that corner
          for(int size = min; size <= n - row && size <= m - column; size++){
              //This will print the upper-left-hand-corner 
              //and the lower-right-hand-corner as (x|y)
              //Place here anything that you want to do with the squares
              System.out.println("(" + column + "|" + row + ") to (" 
                  + (column+size-1) + "|" + (row+size-1) + "), size: " + size);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

One note on n and m: You might not want to hardcode the values for the dimensions of the rectangle. Instead you might want to use:

```
int m = rectangle[0].length;
int n = rectange.length;
```